# Google Map Zoom variable not being recognised

Tags: google-maps

I'm using a Wordpress plugin called RomeLuv Google Maps for Wordpress, which builds Google Maps from map location values in posts' custom meta tags.

The plugin works fine, except for **the zoom level of the map**, which **by default is zoomed in as close as possible** ([example here](http://www.doig.com.au/test/volunteer/map/)).

The zoom level was hard coded to 17 in the plugin code.  I changed this to 10, but the map remains at closest zoom.

The plugin outputs the following code, copied from viewing the source code of the generated web page:

```
<div id="romeluv-global-map" style="width: 100%; height:600px;  "></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("romeluv-global-map"), {
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var marker, i;
        var myIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.doig.com.au/test/volunteer/wp-content/uploads/firstaid.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(32,37));
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-22.9794430, -43.2320800),
        map: map,
        icon: myIcon
        });

        bounds.extend(marker.position);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mousedown", (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent("<p style='width:95%'><a class='romeluv-google-map-link' href='http://www.doig.com.au/test/volunteer/midwife/'><b>Midwife</b></a><br /> <i>Midwifery</i>  <br />Address: <b>Rio De Janeiro, Brazil </b><br /><br /></p>");
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

    //  Fit these bounds to the map
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
</script>
```

Is the zoom level being incorrectly implemented here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the option 'zoom: 10'(or any value).

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case the zoom: 10 you're specifying when initializing the map is being overridden by the map.fitBounds call at the bottom of your code.  Try commenting out that line / removing it and see if things work any better.

Comment: I think you're right.  It's hard to alter this plugin.  Do you know of another plugin to display multiple map locations on a single map?  It would need to include a click-able marker to take the user to the individual job post.